# How do I get BMI correct?

Tags: c++, calculation

Having an issue with my calculation to determine BMI. Please advise me where I am going wrong as the answer always returns as -nan(ind). I'm sure that the problem lies with the calculation itself as I have removed the displayFitnessResults function and simplified the code but I still get the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void getData(float weightP, float heightP)
{
    cout << "Enter indivual's wight in kilograms and height in metres: ";
    cin >> weightP >> heightP;
}

float calcBMI(float weightP, float heightP)
{
    return weightP / (heightP * heightP);
}

void displayFitnessResults(float calcBMI)
{
    if (calcBMI < 18.5)
    {
        cout << "The individuals BIM index is " << calcBMI << " and his/her weight status is underweight";
    }
    else if (calcBMI >= 18.5 && calcBMI <= 24.9)
    {
        cout << "The individuals BIM index is " << calcBMI << " and his/her weight status is healthy";
    }
    else if (calcBMI <= 25 && calcBMI >= 29.9)
    {
        cout << "The individuals BIM index is " << calcBMI << " and his/her weight status is overweight";
    }
    else (calcBMI >= 30);
    {
        cout << "The individuals BIM index is " << calcBMI << " and his/her weight status is obese";
    }
}


int main()
{
    float weight{}, height{}, BMI{};

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(2);

    getData(weight, height);

    BMI = calcBMI(weight, height);

    displayFitnessResults(BMI);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to what Remy said, you should prefer to declare your variables like this `float weight, height, BMI;` The reason is that, had you done, so the compiler would have warned you that you were using *uninitialised variables*, and this would have (hopefully) led you to realise the problem with `getData`. By initialising the variables to meaningless values you hid a potentially useful warning from the compiler.

Comment: `calcBMI <= 25 && calcBMI >= 29.9` is never `true`. Time to get that debugger out.

Comment: First Bug in your code.  What happens if `calcBMI` is `24.95` ?  (Hint: nothing gets printed).  A similar bug exists when `calcBMI==29.95`.

Comment: Code review: Have a function that returns `status` as a string.  Then your display function simply be: `cout << "The individuals BIM index is " << calcBMI << " and his/her weight status is " << GetStatus(calcBMI);`

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you, but these are the parameters that was given in the assignment: 1. Below 18.5 Underweight 2. 18.5‐24.9 Healthy 3. 25.0‐29.9 Overweight 4. 30.0 and above Obese

Comment: Thank you to all the responses, it made my calculation work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getData()` function takes its parameters *by value*, so any modifications it makes to them are not reflected back to the variables in `main()`, thus they are still `0.0` when passed to `calcBMI()`.

You need to pass the parameters *by reference* instead:

```
void getData(float &weightP, float &heightP)
```